# OO design for a custom list displaying different objects

Tags: java, android, oop

Should be fairly simple but I want to get it right before I start coding. Let's say I coded a `CustomLayout` or `CustomListView` class that has a special behaviour on the elements it contains (eg highlighting when hovering above an element on a touchscreen).

I then want this `CustomListView` to be able to display different types of elements, for instance a `Place`, a `Bookmark` or a `SearchResult`. When displaying a `Place` it should display only the name, when displaying a `Bookmark`, it should display the name plus a time stamp for instance.

I know the wrong way to do this, i.e. in the `CustomListView` do something like

> **if** (anInstance **instanceof** Bookmark)

What would be the best way to design my classes?

Comment: A super class (`CustomListElement`) which forces `Place`, `Bookmark` ect. to implement the method you require.

Answer (score 0):

Simply have `CustomLayout`, `Place`, `Bookmark`, etc. contain a method `render()` that renders the elements it contains, or alternatively have it return some sort of handle (like a view or similar) so that whoever is calling `render()` can determine where it should be placed.

All logic regarding how to render would be contained in this function, and would be different depending on what was happening, as you described.

See [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Or may be you can implement the classes for each of these type by subclassing a generic CustomListItem and then implement a Factory that will instantiate and return you the type of item you want.